# When Looping Code through Worksheet Automation Error Exception Occurs

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looping the below code through a worksheet with 30-50 tabs. I keep on getting the error "Automation Error, Exception Occurred". As soon as I click "ok" excel becomes unresponsive and the program closes out. Any thoughts as to why this could be happening?

```
Sub Step19MatchStrike()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRowColumnA As Long
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Index > 3 Then
            LastRowColumnA = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            ws.Range("AA1").Value = "Strike Determination"
            ws.Range("AA2").FormulaArray = "=IF((MATCH(E2,INDEX(Sheet3,(MATCH(A2,INDEX(Sheet3,,1),0)),5),0))>0,""To Keep"",""To Delete"")"
            ws.Range("AA2").Copy ws.Range("AA3:AA" & LastRowColumnA)
            ws.Columns(27).Value = ws.Columns(27).Value
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: at which line you get the error?

Comment: When you get the error, press control-break to see what line it is on, then add that to your question. it probably has something to do with a misuse of double quotes on the formulaarray line.

Comment: I can't tell. It's a systems dialogue box, not the standard Microsoft Visual Basic dialogue box.

Comment: The code works ok. Try reboot excel & machine and try again. Also check if there is any other code executed before or during this code execution period

Comment: Any `Event` based codes present on worksheet?

Comment: Tried rebooting- didn't help. Nothing else is running...

Comment: @urdearboy the above code is all there is

Comment: What is the purpose of this line `ws.Columns(27).Value = ws.Columns(27).Value`? you just overwrite

Comment: @Error 1004 - I believe the purpose is to convert the formulas to their resulting values

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad correct.

Comment: If I revise the above code to `If ws.Index > 3 And ws.Index < 26 Then` it works fine. I just don't want to lock it into a specific sheet, I want to go til the last sheet.